# How to fix decimal numbers for amount fields in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to display the amount fields two digits after the decimal. 
Ex:If salary is 38000 and output should display 38000.00 
If Salary is 25000.4 and output should display 25000.40
If salary is 12500.08 and output should display the same 12500.08

And also when i export the results in tab delimited text, this salary should not be display in double quotation marks.
Ex: 
PayeeID FirstName Salary
100   DEEPA    25000.40

can you please help to make change in xslt.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs ws" xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync"
    xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml"></xsl:output>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <File xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xtt:quotes="csv" xtt:separator="&#xD;&#xA;">

            <xsl:for-each select="ws:Worker_Sync/ws:Worker/ws:Additional_Information">

                <xsl:variable name="Current_date">
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-date()"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <Record xtt:separator="&#9;" xtt:quotes="csv">
                <PayeeID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ws:PayeeID"/>
                </PayeeID>

        <FirstName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ws:FirstName"/>
                </FirstName>

        <Salary>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ws:Salary"/>
                </Salary>

      </Record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Use the [format-number()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-number) function.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this format

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,'#.00')"/>
```